# "Time limit exceeded" when changing order of assignment in python

Tags: python, assignment-operator

I was working with the question reversing group of k nodes in a linked list. When I was writing the assignment operation to do the reversal, I gave:

```py
cur, cur.next, prev = cur.next, prev, cur
```

where `cur` and `prev` denote the current and previous nodes. The most interesting thing happening is that when I give:

```
cur.next, cur, prev = prev, cur.next, cur
```

It is accepted while the former gives me time limit exceeded.

I believe in Python assignment of multiple variables takes those as tuples and only the previous values of all the variables are considered. Then both the statements should be the exact same right? Or am I wrong? Kindly help me out here.

This is a leetcode question and the I am providing the whole code just in case. The line is marked with 3 * and if I alter that line alone the code jumps from accepted to time limit exceeded.

```
 h=jump=ListNode(0)
 h.next=left=right=head
 while True:
            i=0
            while i<k and right:
                i+=1
                right=right.next
            if i==k:
                prev=right
                cur=left
                for _ in range(k):
                    ***cur.next, cur, prev = prev, cur.next, cur***
                jump.next,jump,left=prev,left,right
            else:
                return h.next
```

The above code is accepted. Only when I change the line it is kind of stuck in a cycle, giving time limit exceeded.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about such assignments?

Comment: What do "TLE" and "AC" mean? Please avoid unnecessary acronyms unless they are exceedingly common. Clarity is vital here. Please see [ask].

Comment: The meaning of `cur.next` changes depending on whether or not the new value of `cur` has been assigned yet.  So yes, the order of assignments does matter here.

Comment: @Chris I am sorry, TLE means Time Limit Exceeded while AC means Accepted. I thought that the acronyms are common, will edit accordingly

Comment: @jasonharper In python isn't assignment done as some kind of tuple operation. So each of the values would be assigned to what they were before the whole assignment. That is why for swapping just a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i] would suffice in python right?

Comment: @superbrain Yes I did look at the documentation

Comment: @ExponentialScholiast, thank you for updating your question. Maybe these acronyms are common _on LeetCode.com_, but this isn't LeetCode.com. This is a question and answer site for programmers, and most questions here have nothing to do with programming challenges in general or LeetCode in particular. I've never seen those acronyms before, and I don't think I'm the only one who was confused.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is [from left to right](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment-stmt), so...

```
cur, cur.next, ... = ...
```

The above first assigns to `cur`. And then to `cur.next`, where `cur` is **already the new value**.

```
cur.next, cur, ... = ...
```

This first assigns to `cur.next`, where `cur` is **still the old value**. And then to `cur`.

So there's your difference. You change the `.next` of different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

### Very Good Question!

#### Now I also understand the question! ( ˆ_ˆ )

That's a very common issue in Linked Lists, which we should always pay attention to the order of changes in our statements as we traverse the linked lists or perform any other operations.

The thing is that, if some required orders in our statements would be missed (which is the case here), eventually one of these two conditions would happen:

- Either one Node would miss the link to the next Node and the Node would become linkless, if you will;
- Or one Node would link back to itself (like a circle) and the list would become obsolete;

Your code with the correct order would work perfectly fine without a Time Limit Exceeded (Just tested):

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def reverseKGroup(self, head, k):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :type k: int
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        h = jump = ListNode(0)
        h.next = left = right = head
        while True:
            i = 0
            while i < k and right:
                i += 1
                right = right.next
            if i == k:
                prev = right
                cur = left
                for _ in range(k):
                    cur.next, cur, prev = prev, cur.next, cur
                jump.next, jump, left = prev, left, right
            else:
                return h.next
```

We can also use a helper function. This'd pass without Time Limit Exceeded (TLE):

```
class Solution:
    def reverseKGroup(self, head, k):
        def rev(head, count):
            prev, curr, next = None, head, head
            while count > 0:
                next = curr.next
                curr.next = prev
                prev, curr, count = curr, next, count - 1
            return (curr, prev)
        count, curr = 0, head
        while curr and count < k:
            curr, count = curr.next, count + 1
        if count < k:
            return head
        new_head, prev = rev(head, count)
        head.next = self.reverseKGroup(new_head, k)
        return prev
```

Here are LeetCode's official solutions with explanatory comments:

#### Recursive

```
class Solution:
    
    def reverseLinkedList(self, head, k):
        
        # Reverse k nodes of the given linked list.
        # This function assumes that the list contains 
        # atleast k nodes.
        new_head, ptr = None, head
        while k:
            
            # Keep track of the next node to process in the
            # original list
            next_node = ptr.next
            
            # Insert the node pointed to by "ptr"
            # at the beginning of the reversed list
            ptr.next = new_head
            new_head = ptr
            
            # Move on to the next node
            ptr = next_node
            
            # Decrement the count of nodes to be reversed by 1
            k -= 1
        
        # Return the head of the reversed list
        return new_head
                
    
    def reverseKGroup(self, head: ListNode, k: int) -> ListNode:
        
        count = 0
        ptr = head
        
        # First, see if there are atleast k nodes
        # left in the linked list.
        while count < k and ptr:
            ptr = ptr.next
            count += 1
        
        # If we have k nodes, then we reverse them
        if count == k: 
            
            # Reverse the first k nodes of the list and
            # get the reversed list's head.
            reversedHead = self.reverseLinkedList(head, k)
            
            # Now recurse on the remaining linked list. Since
            # our recursion returns the head of the overall processed
            # list, we use that and the "original" head of the "k" nodes
            # to re-wire the connections.
            head.next = self.reverseKGroup(ptr, k)
            return reversedHead
        return head
```

#### Iterative

```
class Solution:
    
    def reverseLinkedList(self, head, k):
        
        # Reverse k nodes of the given linked list.
        # This function assumes that the list contains 
        # atleast k nodes.
        new_head, ptr = None, head
        while k:
            
            # Keep track of the next node to process in the
            # original list
            next_node = ptr.next
            
            # Insert the node pointed to by "ptr"
            # at the beginning of the reversed list
            ptr.next = new_head
            new_head = ptr
            
            # Move on to the next node
            ptr = next_node
            
            # Decrement the count of nodes to be reversed by 1
            k -= 1
        
        # Return the head of the reversed list
        return new_head
                
    
    def reverseKGroup(self, head: ListNode, k: int) -> ListNode:
        
        ptr = head
        ktail = None
        
        # Head of the final, moified linked list
        new_head = None
        
        # Keep going until there are nodes in the list
        while ptr:
            count = 0
            
            # Start counting nodes from the head
            ptr = head
            
            # Find the head of the next k nodes
            while count < k and ptr:
                ptr = ptr.next
                count += 1

            # If we counted k nodes, reverse them        
            if count == k:
                
                # Reverse k nodes and get the new head
                revHead = self.reverseLinkedList(head, k)
                
                # new_head is the head of the final linked list
                if not new_head:
                    new_head = revHead
                
                # ktail is the tail of the previous block of 
                # reversed k nodes
                if ktail:
                    ktail.next = revHead
                    
                ktail = head 
                head = ptr
        
        # attach the final, possibly un-reversed portion
        if ktail:
            ktail.next = head
        
        return new_head if new_head else head
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-nodes-in-k-group/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! But the code I gave is accepted, the line which had to be changed is given above. If the line marked with *** is changed to the former one, the code is not accepted. Thanks for your time but could you please help me out

Comment: Can you please explain how the order matters in this particular case? All the 3 variables are assigned to the same ones in both statements. And in python it first takes the original values before assignment right? That's why the swap a,b=b,a works. I am sorry to bother you, but could you please explain?

Comment: Oh yeah, just understood! Thank you so much